# Finding class group of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{29})$

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I wondered the class group $G_{29}$ of the cyclotomotic field $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{29})$ today (29 October) which is the second non-trivial class group of the sequence of fields $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$ where$\zeta_p=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}p)$.

For now, I found its class number in [the list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field) of Wikipedia: $$|G_{29}|=8.$$

It also contains the quadratic subfield $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{29})$ if I am not wrong.

I am very far from the main computation. I have no ideas now. Thank you for any help.

Comment: The group is $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$, see [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379702/is-class-group-of-cyclotomic-fields-cyclic). You can find it in Wahsington's book on cyclotomic fields.